# Remove URL parameter and index.php filename from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some push with this, I have website that URL structure looks like this

domain.com/folder/index.php?name=asdasdAs2

How do I remove this part of the URL `index.php?name=` so it looks like this

domain.com/folder/asdasdAs2

The passed value (asdasdAs2) sometimes also contain these symbols ( . ) or ( - ) or ( _ ) so it will look like this (asd.asdAs2) or (asdasd_As2) or (asd-aSd-As2)

I've been trying with this code in my .htaccess file but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*) /folder/index.php?name=$1
```

and this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

and this one too

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$     $1/index.php?name=$2 [L]
```

The last one does the job but only with alphanumeric word  ex.(asdasdAs2) but not on (asd.asd) or (asd_asdas2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file.

***Please make sure to:***

- Keep your .htaccess file along with folder named `folder`.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(folder)/index\.php\?name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.php?name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved. My `.htaccess` file is inside the root folder of the website.
although I didn't cleared the cache before testing it out. But as i remember it's working without deleting the cache too. I tried with your solution too and works perfect. Thank you again

Comment: @MichaelJinston, for your particular scenario its recommended to have it in this way IMHO. Cheers and Happy learning.